# How to keep connection pool for cloud firestore in rails

Tags: connection, google-cloud-firestore, pool

**Rails 5.1** gem 'google-cloud-firestore'

require 'google/cloud/firestore'

I just call `firestore` in backend.

How to keep connect `firestore` working when start backend server rails ??

How to setting this??
Pls help

Comment: You'd better show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i fixed with ConnectionPool of ActiveRecord to setting firestore
tks you :)